# Regex that finds JSON string inside another string

Tags: php, json, regex, string

I would like to extract a JSON string within another string.

Currently I am getting the full string using `file_get_contents` and running the following pattern on the string: https://regex101.com/r/5jAucO/1
which pretty much gives multiple matches.

I would like to extract the JSON string that is saved in `window._sharedData` but haven't been able to achieve that. Does someone have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429182/php-parse-html-extract-script-tags-from-body-and-inject-before-body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include _sharedData in the regex like?
`_sharedData\s*=\s*\{.+\}`

- or with lookbehind:
  `(?<=_sharedData\s=)\s*\{.+\}`
- or take the json from a capturing group:
  `_sharedData\s*=\s*(\{.+\})`

One concern with the lookbehind is if they add an additional whitespace character between _sharedData and = it won't match.

This only works well since there are no linebreaks in the JSON.

Comment: can we do the same thing using javascript ? i want to get _sharedData using javascript

Comment: the regex with the lookbehind wouldn't work in javascript but since the example is trying to capture json within a web page, I would recommend making sure the html is rendered in a dom and then just access the `_sharedData` variable via `window._sharedData` instead.